# get the avg last 4 counts for a date range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have query counting the user signing up EACH day during a date range.

```
select count(*) as c, date(from_unixtime(user.firstaccess)) as date
    from user
    where firstaccess between ? and ?
    group by date(from_unixtime(user.firstaccess))
```

This is working great. 
Now, I am **generating a report** and I want to know the **AVG of the last 4 days of the week**. For example: Today is Wednesday,so I would get the last 4 Wednesdays and get the AVG.
Again, I have this query, working, but I can just think the logic to query each day individually. And not with a date range.
That's what I have

```
select
(
(select count(*) from user where firstaccess between 1456617600-(3600*24*7) and 1456703999-(3600*24*7)) + 
(select count(*) from user where firstaccess between 1456617600-(3600*24*14) and 1456703999-(3600*24*14)) +
(select count(*) from user where firstaccess between 1456617600-(3600*24*14) and 1456703999-(3600*24*14)) +
(select count(*) from user where firstaccess between 1456617600-(3600*24*21) and 1456703999-(3600*24*21))
)
/4
as c
from user
limit 0,1
```

I am using Mysql and PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the average count of users who signed up for the first time today, 7 days, 14 days ago and 21 days ago, you can use:

```
select count(*)/4 as avg_new_users
from
user
where 
date(from_unixtime(user.firstaccess))=CURDATE() or date(from_unixtime(user.firstaccess))=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) or date(from_unixtime(user.firstaccess))=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY) or date(from_unixtime(user.firstaccess))=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 21 DAY)
```

Comment: Nice SQL!! It does work for a specific date. Although still does not for a range of dates.

Comment: Do you have a table where you are pulling the range of dates from (which contains all the dates?)

Comment: I actually don't. Would not be weird having a table with dates for that? Although I gave up trying to get all this info in just one query. I am querying inside the foreach, and caching the results. I tried you query, but had to rollback to mine because of performance issues. Since the date functions can't use the indexes, the queries were way slower than mine using timestamps. I Appreciated your time

Answer (score 0):

```
select AVG(column_name) as c, date(from_unixtime(user.firstaccess)) as date
    from user
    where firstaccess between ? and ?
    group by date(from_unixtime(user.firstaccess))
```